# using data from a promise in an angular controller

Tags: angularjs, promise

Inside of my controller I am calling my service that contains an array of data that I would like to work with in `DrinkLibrary`.`DrinkLibrary` has a `getDrinks`-method that is getting the data from my database.

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
    console.log('connected');

    var drinkSet = function(){
        DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
            var caffeineData = data;
        });
    };
    drinkSet();
});
```

When I call `success()` I am getting the data that I want inside of `caffeineData`.  When I call `drinkSet()` I am getting the data that I need inside of my browser console. In the controller. However, I am limited to `caffeineData` exist inside of the `drinkSet`-method.

Is there a better way to set this up so that I might be able to use this data in a chart?

Comment: If youre new to angular I highly recommend you to read new tutorials and not to use $scope if not needed. Use [ControllerAs](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I am hoping to have a better grasp of layout and best practices as I continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want the `data` to be available? There are a number of things you can do. For example:

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$rootScope,$scope){
    console.log('connected');

    var drinkSet = function(){
        DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
            var caffeineData = data; // local only to this function
            $scope.caffeineData = data; // local to this controller
            $rootScope.caffeineData = data; // local to the application
        });
    };
    drinkSet();
});
```

References:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Comment: You forgot to add ```window.caffeineData = data; // local to the window instance```

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira - fair enough, but I don't advise polluting the global.

Answer (score 1):

Since `caffeineData` is a local variable so it will not be available in the view. You have to set the data to a `$scope` then you can access it in your view.

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
    console.log('connected');

    var drinkSet = function(){
        DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
            $scope.caffeineData = data;
        });
    };
    drinkSet();
});
```

Inside the view. Based on the object type of caffeineData you can add your logic in the view.

```
<div>{{caffeineData}}</div>
```

You can learn more about angular scope here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/s8mWpCTV6bvxmR3hOLOM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Shankar for taking the time to respond.  I am trying to get my data to be usable inside of the controller, but outside of the promise.  I assumed that I would be able to define an array similar to what Eric showed me below, but I am getting back an empty array below.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the data to the controller `$scope` and use it in your html

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
   console.log('connected');

   var loadDrinks = function(){
     DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
        $scope.caffeineData = data;
     });
    };
   loadDrinks();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-controller="analysisController">
    <li ng-repeat="drink in caffeineData">
       <label ng-bind="drink.name"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the response data outside that function, try instantiating a variable first, before defining your drinkSet function. Assuming your data to be set into caffeineData is an array, like this:

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
  console.log('connected');

  var caffeineData = []; // could also set via $scope.caffeineData
  var drinkSet = function(){
      DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
          caffeineData = data;
      });
  };
  drinkSet();
});
```

By instantiating it outside the function, it won't be kept private to the function (JS has [function level scope for variables](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)). The benefit here is that if anything is set to build in the DOM from yoru caffeineData var, you can have it build correctly over an empty array, before it populates.

There's one more improvement we can make to your controller here, assuming nothing else happens inside your success callback, other than set the data; have a look:

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
  console.log('connected');

  var caffeineData = []; // could also set via $scope.caffeineData
  DrinkLibrary.getDrinks().success(function(data){
      caffeineData = data;
  });
});
```

As to your wanting to use this data in a chart, you could define your chart initiation call inside the success callback, to only invoke the chart building function on successful setting of your data.

---

[Edit]
Per my comment, here's an updated version I suggest you try. You'll note I put the console.log *inside* the success/error callbacks, to ensure your dump to the console is after the promise has resolved, either way. I've included the comments and additional callback parameters as shown in the [$http.get example from the AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), in which the comments talk specifically about the async nature of promises.

```
app.controller('analysisController',function(Drink,DrinkLibrary,$scope){
  console.log('connected');

  $scope.caffeineData = []; // could also set via $scope.caffeineData
  DrinkLibrary.getDrinks()
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
          // this callback will be called asynchronously
          // when the response is available
          $scope.caffeineData = data;
          console.log("Response code of the GET was: "+status);
          console.log("Data received: "+data);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        $scope.caffeineData = null; //no data :'-(
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("status: " + status);
        //console.log("headers: " + headers);
        //console.log("config: " + JSON.parse(config));
      });
});
```

[/Edit]

Comment: Thanks eric.  This is essentially what I am trying to do.  I would like to move the data outside of the promise.  However, I must be doing something wrong in the service.  When I call console.log(caffeineData outside of the success I get back an empty array.

Comment: Well, when your controller first fires the console.log, it's likely that the promise (what AngularJS uses with its factories/services, like $http) has yet to be resolved. In fact, that's the whole point of [the promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), that it will allow you to continue working with your variable and will automatically update without your need for intervention. I'll update my answer with a modified version I suggest you try.